# Find mobile device on network

Tags: networking, ip-address, wireless-access-point, mac-address, mobile-phone

I'm trying to write a small program that will poll the network for certain IP addresses or MAC addresses (though MAC doesn't seem to show up past my WAP).

My networking isn't very strong but many mobile devices don't support ping on the network (I'm looking at you iPhone).

Is there a fairly easy way to poll all network addresses on the network regardless of whether they will reply to a ping?

Comment: can use nmap, using as arguments -Pn

Comment: Is there a reason you're reinventing the wheel?

Comment: yes becuase I am writing code for a netduino using the .net framework but regardless of the language the users who run it might not have nmap installed.